# How do I solve Websphere MQ server queue read race condition?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, ibm-was

I have a 4 node websphere application server cluster running some application. The application listens to a queue of websphere mq server. I have created the jms resources in the cluster scope, so all the nodes connect to the same queue manager, and the open input count for the queue is 4 in mq explorer. The problem is if a message is published to the queue, one of the nodes grabs the message and starts processing, but it throws an error saying the message header is incorrect. When I shut down 3 nodes and kept only one running, the application on that node read the message and started processing just fine. I thought that read contention was not a problem in mq, but the facts point to the other direction. Is there some way to set some property in the queue like read lock or something like a scheduler which distributes the messages to 4 nodes fairly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the message under syncpoint using a `GET` instead of a `BROWSE`, no other thread can retrieve it unless and until `ROLLBACK` is issued.  If the message is OK to process, then issue a `COMMIT` when done.

On the other hand, if you `BROWSE` the messages then all threads can retrieve the same message.

Whatever is going on is not attributable to thread contention over the same message somehow corrupting the message.  Regardless of whether the message is browsed or destructively retrieved, WMQ assures the integrity and atomic operation of the call.  To diagnose this, it will be necessary to have more information as to the exact error you are seeing, including a print of the linked exception which will contain the transport provider's native return code.

Comment: OK so I have been a moron, the application required a input xsd which i put in only one node's file system. So this is not really a problem. Can I improve the setup by implementing something like a scheduler which server the message to all 4 nodes in a round robin manner ??

Comment: WMQ will distribute messages round-robin, provided they come in faster than any one node can process them.  However, for efficiency when a GET request is made, it is pushed onto a stack so it's possible when they arrive slowly that only one or two threads will process them.  You can use the cooperative browsing feature to write a message dispatcher to do round robin but honestly it hardly seems worth the effort.  To test message distribution, load a queue, then copy all the messages to the input queue at once.  Then you will see round-robin behavior.